# Traduzir Captcha

Tags: vba, excel-vba

estou desenvolvendo uma rotina que pesquisa os débitos e restrições de veículos no Detran, e para realizar o download do documento, eu preciso passar por uma validação Captcha, e isso já esta me tirando o sono. Gostaria de saber se alguém conseguiu passar por essa validação utilizando VBA ou conseguiu fazer algo para solucionar este tipo de "problema".

O site que estou trabalhando é este: http://www.detran.sp.gov.br/wps/portal/portaldetran/cidadao/veiculos/servicos/pesquisaDebitosRestricoesVeiculos

Ate o momento estou utilizando uma mensagem dizendo para o usuário digitar o Captcha e depois aperto OK para que o processo continue, praticamente esta pronto, só esta parte que esta me atrapalhando bastante.

Comment: M Marins, sua pergunta não está clara, tu colocou um título deixando subentendido que quer "traduzir captcha" depois vc descreve algo que parece que quer "quebrar" o captcha de um site, qual seria sua necessidade real? descreva de forma mais clara e objetiva, para podermos te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Quebra de captcha é um problema não muito trivial, precisa conhecer um pouquinho de processamento de imagens, mesmo para os casos simples.

Essa imagem de captcha é simples de quebrar comparada com a maioria dos captchas que existem por ae. A letra é bem destacada do fundo e as letras estão bem separadas entre si.

O algoritmo seria mais ou menos:

1. Separar cada letra
2. Fazer o reconhecimento por letra - As letras parecem não variar a rotação, então um simples casamento exato entre a letra recortada e o alfabeto pré-classificado parece ser o suficiente.

Infelizmente eu não sei VB, por isso vou escrever em python o código, mas acredito que seja simples adaptar para Visual Basic usando [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), um wrapper em .NET para o OpenCV.

#### Passo 1 - Separar as letras

Vou pegar um exemplo da pagina e rodar passo a passo o algoritmo.
[image: original]

Esses passos são conhecidos em processamento de imagem como remoção de fundo. A ideia dessa técnica é remover da imagem o que não é importante, deixando em uma cor única, e destacar o objeto importante, deixando em outra cor, de forma que seja simples pegar as coordenadas dos objetos de interesse (Na Wikipédia tem mais informações - [Background Subtraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_subtraction))

O primeiro passo é transformar a imagem colorida em imagem em tons de cinza.

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

O resultado é a imagem abaixo:

[image: gray]

Depois disso, para destacar as letras brancas, vamos usar uma operação morfológica chamada [dilatação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)). Ela vai fazer as letras ficarem "gordinhas", reforçando a área dos objetos de interesse.

```
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
dilated = cv2.dilate(gray, kernel)
```

O resultado aplicado na imagem em tons de cinza é a imagem abaixo:

[image: dilated]

Agora que temos a letra bem destacada, podemos transformar o fundo em preto e as letras em branco apenas olhando a cor delas. Os pixels que forem menor que o valor 127 vamos pintar de preto e os maiores vamos pintar de branco. Essa técnica é chamada [Thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)).

```
_, bw = cv2.threshold(dilated, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

O resultado do threshold na imagem dilatada é o abaixo:

[image: black & white]

Bacana, agora o fundo é todo preto e as letras todas brancas. Agora temos que separar cada letra, e para isso, o opencv já tem uma função bacana, que dá o mesmo valor para todos os pixels vizinhos que tem a mesma cor.

```
total, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(bw)
```

total vai ter a quantidade de componentes, incluindo o background, e markers vai ser uma imagem com os componentes conectados (cada letra) pintados da mesma cor. Ela desenhada abaixo:

[image: markers]

Agora basta achar as coordenadas de cada letra. Para isso usamos um método chamada findContours que irá achar os contornos de cada letra.

```
# filtra os componentes, deixando apenas os com mais de 10px e menos de 1 mil px
images = [numpy.uint8(labels==i) * 255 for i in range(total) if numpy.uint8(labels==i).sum() > 10 and numpy.uint8(labels==i).sum() < 1000]

# faz uma copia da imagem em preto e branco, so pra visualizacao
img = cv2.cvtColor(bw, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)


# pinta retangulos em volta de cada componente
color = (255.0, 0.0, 0.0)

for label in images:
    # encontra os contornos para cada componente
    countours = cv2.findContours(label, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # calcula o retangulo em volta dos contornos
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(countours[0])

    # e pinta ele
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), color, 1)
```

O resultado são os retângulos desenhados em volta de cada letra, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: black and white - rectangle]

Agora com as coordenadas x, y, altura e largura de cada letra é trivial recortá-las e salvá-las num diretório. Essas letras devem então ser classificadas de alguma forma (todos os 'a' no mesmo diretório, por exemplo, todos os 'b', e assim por diante).

#### Passo 2 - Fazer o reconhecimento

Agora que você tem uma base boa de letras classificadas e sabe como separar as letras em um captcha novo, basta você recortar cada letra e comparar com todas as letras da sua base, bem na força bruta mesmo. O Opencv tem uma função que faz isso, chamado matchTemplate. Ela tem vários métodos para calcular a diferencia entre 2 imagens, por experiencia, eu costumo usar o método TM_CCOEFF_NORMED.

Imaginando que você tenha 1 letra recortada que queira reconhecer, e uma lista de imagens como template, você pode usar o método abaixo, que te dará o melhor casamento.

```
# Busca o melhor template p/ uma letra
def search_for_letter(image, letter, templates):
    best = 2 ** 32

    pos  = None

    for template in templates:
        # busca o template na imagem, usando o metodo passado
        match = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

        # encontra a pontuacao e a localizacao do template
        minVal,maxVal,minLoc,maxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(match)

        if best < maxVal:
            pos = {
                'error': maxVal,
                'location': maxLoc,
                'letter': letter
            }
            best = maxVal

    return pos
```

Agora você pode usar esse método num laço, para achar todas as letras contidas na imagem, algo como o metodo abaixo:

```
# itera em cima de todas as letras para achar
# o melhor resultado
def search(file, templates):
    matches = []

    # esse cut_and_binarize eh todo o passo 1 
    image = cut_and_binarize(file)

    for letter in templates:
        pos = search_for_letter(image, letter, templates[letter])

        if pos is not None:
            matches.append(pos)

    # ordena os melhores casamentos
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x['error'],reverse=True)

    # pega os 6 melhores casamentos e ordena em X
    return sorted(matches[:6], key=lambda x:x['location'][0])
```

Com isso, acredito que você consiga mais de 90% de acerto no reconhecimento desse captcha. Como eu disse no começo, entender processamento de imagens é importante para automatizar o reconhecimento de captchas, mas conhecendo as técnicas básicas, o trabalho é simples.